# How to fill Gridview select fields

Tags: asp.net

In my application i have a Grid.The grid have some fields like bound field, Template field, check box.
My issue is i want to fill grid with one bound field and one Dropdown from the Datasource.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdSetupBillingDetails" OnRowDataBound="grdSetupBillingDetails_OnRowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" Width="100%">                          
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Check AssetSubType" SortExpression="CheckAssetSubType">
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100px" />
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAssetSubType" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("ActiveFlag")%>' />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="AssetSubType">
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="150px" /> 
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="center" Width="150px" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:templatefield headertext="Bill Period">
                                    <itemtemplate>
                                    <asp:dropdownlist runat="server" id="cboBillPeriod"></asp:dropdownlist>
                                    </itemtemplate>
                                </asp:templatefield>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fees" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SortExpression="Fees">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFees" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Fees") %>' Style="width: 100px;
                                    text-align: left;" MaxLength="12"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>                                                                         
                            </Columns>
                      </asp:GridView>
```

Any one please help me.

Comment: if you want to bind your grid only two column,so what about other columns.Because you are defined more than two columns.Do you want to fill blank.

Answer (score 2):

You have to find the dropdownlist on RowDatabound event and assign the datasource to the dropdownlist there .

```
protected void grdSetupBillingDetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList cboBillPeriod = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("cboBillPeriod");
            if (null != cboBillPeriod)
            {
                //Your combobox bind Code

                //cboBillPeriod.DataSource = dt;
                //cboBillPeriod.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The RowDataBound event would work, as Abhishek suggests. If you want to keep the binding tied directly to the drop-down, and not the grid, you could bind the drop-down to a Data Source (e.g., ObjectDataSource, EntityDataSource) if you are using data Sources in your application. Then it will bind every time it is rendered.

If you're not using data sources, you can fill the data on the Initi event of the drop-down. something like:

Web Form:

```
<asp:dropdownlist runat="server" id="cboBillPeriod" OnInit="cboBillPeriod_Init" />
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void cboBillPeriod_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList cboBillPeriod = (DropDownList)sender;
        if (null != cboBillPeriod)
        {
            //Your combobox bind Code

            //cboBillPeriod.DataSource = dt;
            //cboBillPeriod.DataBind();
        }
    }
```